What does "on one's ear" mean
I believe the phrase "on one's ear" means easily, or effortlessly.  However my hard copy COD doesn't mention it, nor do a couple of online phrase dictionaries that I have consulted.  It seems the phrase is more obscure than I had thought.  Am I in the right ball park when it comes to the meaning of this phrase?

It is not possible to give an answer without context. The importance of context (source, author and circumstances) cannot be overestimated. If you have a published source, please give it. If you do not have a published source, you may wish to wait until you do.

Are you thinking of out on one's ear?

Where did you hear or read this expression? Why do you think it means easily/effortlessly? What dictionaries have you consulted?

I've never heard the expression.  "play it by ear" is common enough, and it means to approach a situation without a fixed plan but to see what happens and to respond reactively.  "We'll just play it by ear."  I suppose one could stretch that phrase to express the idea that a  particular situation was simple and easy enough to be handled without much preparation or planning.

And there's also the musical ability to 'play by ear' which is to be able to play a piece of music without having to read the sheet music,  to play it just by listening to it, which also has the sense of "being able to play with ease" or with great facility.
